# Positive linear combinations of intervals

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, linear-programming, numerical-linear-algebra, interpolation

Given two intervals at $i\in\{0,1\}$ $I_i=[-a_i,a_i]$ where $0<a_0<a_1=1-a_0<1$ and a third interval $I=[-a,a]$ where $0<a<\frac{1}2$, **when** is there an $\alpha,\beta\in\Bbb R$ such that $\alpha I_0 +\beta I_1\subseteq[-a,a]$ with $\alpha+\beta=1$, $\alpha,\beta>0$? That is if $x_0\in I_0, x_1\in I_1$,  $\alpha x_0 +\beta x_1\in I$ should hold true.

Comment: If $\alpha < 0$, what does $\alpha I_1$ mean please?

Comment: $-|\alpha|I_1$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Observe that the requirement
>   $$\forall x_0 \in I_0, x_1 \in I_1, \alpha x_0 + \beta x_1 \in I\tag{1}$$ 
>   is equivalent to
>   $$
> \alpha a_0 + \beta a_1 \leq a \tag{2}
> $$

*proof*:

- We first prove that **if (1) holds, then (2) holds**.

Let $x_0 = a_0$ and $x_1 = a_1$. Easy to see that $x_0 \in I_0$ and $x_1 \in I_1$, thus by (1), we have
$$
\alpha x_0 + \beta x_1 = \alpha a_0 + \beta a_1 \leq a
$$

- Next, we prove **if (2) holds, then (1) holds**.

If $x_0 \in I_0$ and $x_1 \in I_1$, then we can bound $\alpha x_0 + \beta x_1$ as follows:
$$
-a \leq -(\alpha a_0 + \beta a_1) \leq \alpha x_0 + \beta x_1 \leq \alpha a_0 + \beta a_1 \leq a
$$
thus $\alpha x_0 + \beta x_1 \in I$.

---

> According to the discussion above, we only need to find when there is $0 < \alpha, \beta < 1$ with $\alpha + \beta = 1$ such that
>   $$
> \alpha a_0 + \beta a_1 \leq a \tag{3}
> $$

Substituting $\beta = 1 - \alpha$ into (3), we get
$$
\alpha a_0 + (1 - \alpha) a_1 \leq a
$$

- When $a_1 > a > a_0$, let $\alpha = \frac{a_1 - a}{a_1 - a_0}$, thus $1 > \alpha > 0$. We have
  $$
  \alpha a_0 + (1 - \alpha)a_1 = a_1 + \alpha(a_0 - a_1) = a
  $$

Thus when $a_1 > a > a_0$, there exist $\alpha = \frac{a_1-a}{a_1 - a_0}$ and $\beta = 1- \alpha$ satisfying the requirement.

- When $a \geq a_1$, this case is impossible since $a_1 > 0.5$ and $a < 0.5$.
- When $a \leq a_0$, we have
  $$
  \alpha a_0 + (1 - \alpha)a_1 > \alpha a + (1 - \alpha)a = a
  $$

Thus when $a \leq a_0$, no solution exists.

---

> In summary, there exist $0 < \alpha, \beta < 1$ with $\alpha + \beta = 1$ satisfying the requirement in question *iff* $a > a_0$.

Comment: does not make sense.

Comment: It seems that you've edited your question again.

Comment: @Turbo I've modified my answer according to your edits. Please recheck my answer.

Comment: I think the answer is wrong.

Comment: @Turbo Could you please elaborate it? Maybe you have the correct answer? Or I've misunderstood your question?

Comment: $a>a_2>a_1$ does not make sense since we are looking at a convex combination.

Comment: @Turbo It's $a_1 > a > a_2$ in my answer.

Comment: Please change your notation to the format in the question. It is unclear.

Comment: Also I am seeking $\alpha,\beta>0$ not just in $\Bbb R$.

Comment: @Turbo I've changed $\alpha \in \Re$ to $0 < \alpha < 1$. I don't change $I_1$, $I_2$ to $I_0$, $I_1$ since in your question, you still use the notation $a_1$, $a_2$.

Comment: Sorry about this, I changed, could you also make change? I still see $\Bbb R$ in last line.

Comment: @Turbo Fixed. Feel free to ask if any problems. :)

Comment: added new question http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1308603/real-linear-combinations-of-intervals

Comment: You think you can solve other question as well?