# Real linear combinations of intervals

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-programming

Given intervals at $i\in\{0,1\}$ $I_i=[-a_i,a_i]$ where $0<a_0<a_1<1$ and a third interval $I=[-a,a]$ where $0<a<{1}$, **when** is there an $\alpha,\beta\in\Bbb R$ such that $\alpha I_0 +\beta I_1 =\{\alpha x +\beta y:x\in I_0, y\in I_1\}\subseteq[-a,a]$ with $\alpha+\beta=1$?

That is if $x_0\in I_0, x_1\in I_1$,  $\alpha x_0 +\beta x_1\in I$ should hold true.

$-\infty<\alpha,\beta<\infty$ is range.

clear $a\in(a_0,a_1)$ is always possible even with $\alpha,\beta\in(0,1)$ by convex combination arguments.

**QUESTIONS**

**1.** If $a<a_0$ then does $\frac{1}2<a<a_0<a_1<1$ or  $0<a<a_0<a_1<\frac{1}2$ hold?

**2.** Is $a>a_1$ always possible?

Comment: Could you specify what you mean by the $+$ operator in $\alpha I_0 + \beta I_1$.

Comment: added modification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Part I

We first prove that

> $$
> \forall x_0 \in I_0, x_1 \in I_1, \ \alpha x_0 + \beta  x_1 \in I \tag{1}
> $$
>   is equivalent to
>   $$
> |\alpha|a_0 + |\beta|a_1 \leq a \tag{2}
> $$

**proof:**

- First, prove **if  (1) holds, then (2) holds**.

Let $x_0 = $**sign**$(\alpha)a_0$, $x_1 =$**sign**$(\beta)a_1$, where the function **sign**$(x)$ returns the sign of $x$. Easy to observe that $x_0 \in I_0$ and $x_1 \in I_1$. Thus by (1), we have
$$
\alpha x_0 + \beta x_1 = |\alpha| a_0 + |\beta| a_1 \in I
$$
which implies
$$
|\alpha| a_0 + |\beta| a_1 \leq a
$$

- Next, prove **if (2) holds, then (1) holds**.

For $\forall x_0 \in I_0, x_1 \in I_1$, we can bound $\alpha x_0 + \beta x_1$ as follows:
$$
-(|\alpha| a_0 + |\beta| a_1) \leq \alpha x_0 + \beta x_1 \leq |\alpha| a_0 + |\beta| a_1
$$
Since (2) holds, thus we have
$$
-a \leq \alpha x_0 + \beta x_1 \leq a
$$
implying 
$$
\alpha x_0 + \beta x_1 \in I
$$

**EDIT: A More Intuitive Proof**

Observe that
$$\alpha I_0 = [\ -|\alpha|a_0,\ |\alpha|a_0\ ] \\
\beta I_1 = [\ -|\beta|a_1, \ |\beta|a_1\ ]
$$

Thus
$$
\alpha I_0 + \beta I_1 = [\ -(|\alpha|a_0 + |\beta|a_1),\ |\alpha|a_0 + |\beta|a_1\ ]
$$

implying
$$
\alpha I_0 + \beta I_1 \in I \Leftrightarrow |\alpha|a_0 + |\beta|a_1 \leq a
$$

---

### Part II

> According to the discussion in Part I, **we only need to find when there exist $-\infty < \alpha, \beta <\infty$ with $\alpha + \beta = 1$ such that $|\alpha|a_0 + |\beta|a_1 \leq a$ holds**. Substituting $\beta = 1 - \alpha$, we have
>   $$
> |\alpha|a_0 + |1 - \alpha|a_1 \leq a 
> $$

We discuss for different cases below:

- **Case 1. $a \geq a_1$**

Let $\alpha = \frac{a + a_1}{a_0 + a_1} > 1$. Then
$$
|\alpha|a_0 + |1 - \alpha|a_1 = \alpha a_0 + (\alpha - 1) a_1 = \alpha (a_0 + a_1) - a_1 = a
$$
Therefore, when $a \geq a_1$, there exist $\alpha = \frac{a+a_1}{a_0 + a_1}$, $\beta = 1 - \alpha$ such that (1) holds.

- **Case 2. $a < a_0$**

We have
$$
|\alpha|a_0 + |1 - \alpha|a_1 > |\alpha|a + |1 - \alpha|a = (|\alpha| + |1 - \alpha|)a \geq a
$$
Here, the fact $|x + y| \leq |x| + |y|, \forall x, y\in\Re$ is used.

Therefore, it is impossible to find a solution in this case.

- **Case 3. $a_0 \leq a < a_1$**

Easy to show that $\alpha = \frac{a_1 - a}{a_1 - a_0}$ is a solution.

---

> In summary, when $a \geq a_0$, there exist $\alpha, \beta \in \Re$ with $\alpha + \beta = 1$ such that (1) holds.

Comment: so no solution if $a<a_0$?

Comment: Yes. As proved.

Comment: @Turbo I added a more intuitive proof to show the equivalence between (1) and (2).